# Quarterly wilcoxon test in R

Tags: r, filter

I'm a new user to R. I need to run wilcoxon test on a large set of data. Currently I have a whole year of transaction data (each transaction is categorized by quarter, say Q12014) and was able to get a result for the complete set. My code is as follows (with ties broken by transaction amount):

```
> total$reRank=NA               
> total$reRank[order(total$Rank,-total$TxnAmount.x)]=1:length(total$Rank)
> Findings=total$reRank[total$Findings==1]      
> NOFindings=total$reRank[total$Findings==0]
> wilcox.test(Findings,NOFindings,na.action=na.omit,alternative='less',exact=F)
```

Now that I was asked to run wilcoxon test quarter by quarter, what code shall I use to filter the data by each quarter?

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, it's difficult to give you exact code specific to your data.

However, it seems like your problem can be answered with `library(dplyr)`

```
library(dplyr)
quarter1Data <- filter(fullData, Quarter == "Q12014")
quarter2Data <- filter(fullData, Quarter == "Q22014")
```

And so on. See [this page](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) for a more in depth explanation on how to use this package.

You can then re-run your existing code replacing your `total` dataset with these smaller datasets. There is likely a more efficient way to do this, but without knowing the structure of your dataset, this is the simplest method I can think of.